# Оптимизация картинок средствами php

Tags: php, wordpress

Добрый день возник такой вопрос, создавал очередной сайт на WP и заметил что несмотря на все предупреждения, клиент не соблюдает базовых правил сжатия картинок по качеству для того что бы была хорошая оценка в google speed.

И вот избежания в дальнейшем неприятных споров что "-я вам говорил а вы меня как обычно не слушали что надо делать", "-вы обещали хотя бы 90 а получилось почему то 15".

Задался вопросом базового сжимания качества картинок то есть человек загрузил поставил куда надо на сайт а php уже все сам сделал. Так как работаю с WP не находил способов (да и думаю что это будет костыль) как при загрузке сразу сжимать картинки (так как даже базовые миниатюры типа thumb гугл все равно просить сжимать хоть и на 1-2 кб и падает оценка на 20-30 если таких файлов больше 10) и тем более при обновлении оболочки такой костыль слетит (клиент всегда хочет самую свежую версию хоть и не всегда она работает стабильно).

Плагины вообще не подходят так как самое главное клиент вообще не хочет видеть их на сайте, большая часть таких проектов полностью ручные либо половина платна+не работает, другая половина просто не работает так как бесплатная.

Есть ли способ при получении картинки то есть get_the_post_thumbnail_url(null, 'thumbnail') взять из нее картинку(в данном случае url!!это важно) сжать его хотя бы на 20-30% и перезаписать и это все должно происходить средствами php

Перепробовал уже с 10 разных оптимизаторов начиная от базовых типа http://php.net/manual/ru/function.imagejpeg.php
заканчивая самопальными кодами типа 
https://github.com/psliwa/image-optimizer

Все оно не работает, либо работает на выгрузке файла на сервер либо на перезаписи в данную папку с похожим именем, но ни один не работает так что бы именно 
взять файл 
$img = get_the_post_thumbnail_url(null, 'thumbnail')
передать его в обработчик с параметром и получить уже готовый файл 
$opz = optimizer($img,75)

Вообще уже не знаю куда копать с такой инфой так как примеров просто 0 или они все не рабочие. 
Буду очень благодарен за ответ на данный вопрос! и с меня +

Comment: Я-бы копал в сторону изменения условий задачи. Есть какие-то бесплатные плагины оптимизирующие заливаемые изображения, вполне неплохо работают (мне лично не нравятся, но это моя вкусовщина). Глупо использовать WP и чураться плагинов. Главное знать меру и стараться оценивать качество используемых плагинов. Так-же можно использовать cli утилиты оптимизирующие изображения, регулярно (с помощью cron) прогонять через них все свежезалитые изображения. Ссылки на несколько таких утилит даны в рекомендациях того самого google page speed

Comment: Можно вообще поставить модуль Google PageSpeed на Apache или nginx (я ставил). Работает.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Данный вопрос решил с помощью данной библиотеки http://php.net/manual/ru/book.imagick.php
Все довольно просто подключаем на сервер если нет или просто работаем если есть, очень много функций для работы и почти все известные и часто используемые форматы. Советую!